# Evaluating 2 variable function using bind(func,_1,_2) function

Tags: c++, gcc, bind

I am testing an example code to implement bind(func,_1,_2) function. the code is the following:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;
int multiply(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
int main()
{
    auto f = bind(multiply, 5, _1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "5 * " << i << " = " << f(i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

a very simple code which should just return the first 9 multiples of 5.

Now, I've update my gcc compiler (basically removed the old one and went through the ordinary installation process, going from 4.2.1 to 4.6 - don't know why it didn't download the latest directly...) but I'm not sure if the g++ command is using the latest. if I press

```
g++ --version
```

I get

```
g++ (GCC) 4.6.0
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

however, when I try to compile my code, this is what I get:

```
test.cpp:5:17: error: ‘placeholders’ is not a namespace-name
test.cpp:5:29: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:14:10: error: ‘f’ does not name a type
test.cpp:17:44: error: ‘f’ was not declared in this scope
```

I don't get it. the namespace should be within the header, and the header should be within the version of gcc I have (4.6.0), and yet I still get compilation errors
help pleeeease, this thing is driving me crazy :(

Comment: Did you forget -std=c++0x?

Comment: sorry, don't know even what's that supposed to mean :\

Comment: That probably indicates to the compiler that you're enabling c++11 features, since you're obviously using them. If you have a makefile, you'll add it to the list of flags.

Comment: @Gigi are you invoking the compiler with something like `g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp -o test`?

Comment: I didn't even know of the extra command -std=c++ox, in fact before I was simply typing "g++ test.cpp -o test"
BUT NOW I DID AND IT WORKS!!!! thank you thank you thank you guys :D